# China Southern airline canceled their Flights and not didn't refund any money

Tags: bookings, airlines, china-southern-airlines

I bought China Sothern airline from Lahore Pk to SFO US and traveled on this flight, later I needed to changed dates for return and I paid the extra $500 for the date change. The problem is that China Southern has canceled all their flights which use Indian airspace to go to Pakistan because of tension between both countries. Due to this reason,=I can't use the return ticket. They are just pushing dates ahead and not resuming their operations even when most of the airlines already resumed their operations. Am I entitled to any refund because they are not refunding any money back?  I need to go back asap.

Comment: Check their conditions of carriage and the contract fine print. Additionally check if Pakistan Civil Aviation Authority has rules covering delayed and canceled flights.